# Haskell: Compose a function of specific type with one of general type?

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, typeclass, function-composition

I was writing a quick one-liner in GHCi and tried to compose sum with map. I figured the reason it failed is because map gives output of a general type [b] whereas sum takes in specific input Num a => [a]. However, there is nothing wrong with this code assuming that the output of the map function is type Num b => [b].

I thought writing a restricting type declaration might work (although I guess that prevents you from doing it in GHCi) but it still didn't:

```
myFunc :: Num b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> b
myFunc = sum . map
```

Gave me the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[[a] -> b]'
            with actual type `[a] -> [b]'
Expected type: (a -> b) -> [[a] -> b]
  Actual type: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `map'
In the expression: sum . map
```

Is there any way to do this? Maybe I am just missing something obvious (new to Haskell).

Comment: Try `myFunc f = sum . map f`. `(.)` composes "unary" functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum . map` isn't a definition you're looking for. Observe that

```
 (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

The dot operator accepts two **unary** functions. It doesn't work as `map` takes two arguments:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

One of possible solutions would be to explicitly bind `map`'s first argument:

```
myFunc :: Num c => (a -> c) -> [a] -> c
myFucc f = sum . map f
```

Alternatively you could use [`curry`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:curry) and [`uncurry`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) and achieve the same result.

```
myFunc = curry $ sum . uncurry map
```

Comment: Another point-free definition being `(sum .) . map` or `sum .: map` where `(.:) = (.) . (.)`.

Comment: "The dot operator accepts two unary functions. It doesn't work ..." Well all functions are technically unary functions; "multi-argument" functions are just unary functions that return other functions. So it doesn't "not work" because map takes two arguments; it just works in a way other than the OP intended